# Last digit on $3^{100}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How to find the last digit on $3^{100}$?
Is there any proper method to solve such questions without calculator of course?

Comment: Hint: ${\rm mod}\ 10\!:\,\ 3^2\equiv\color{#0a0}{ -1}\,\Rightarrow\,3^4\equiv (\color{#0a0}{-1})^2\equiv\color{#c00} 1\,\Rightarrow\,3^{4N}\equiv\color{#c00}1^N\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\,3^{4N+K}\equiv 3^K$

Comment: At least five of the eight (!) answers say exactly the same thing....

Comment: @lab This is *not* a duplicate of the link in lab's comment since it is a much simpler problem, needing only the last digit, not the last two.

Comment: LastDigits of $\left. 3^n\,\right\vert_{\ n\ \geq\ 1}\ =\ 3,9,7,1,3\ldots$. Just count...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solving questions like these are pretty simple once you know a certain trick:

Let's work out the first few terms of $x = 3^n$

- When n = 0: | x = 1 | The last digit is 1
- When n = 1: | x = 3 | The last digit is 3
- When n = 2: | x = 9 | The last digit is 9
- When n = 3: | x = 27 | The last digit is 7
- When n = 4: | x = 81 | The last digit is 1
- When n = 5: | x = 243 | The last digit is 3

**There is a pattern!** 1,3,9,7,1,3,9,7,1,3,9,7,1,3,9,7,1,3,9,7... and so on. The pattern repeats itself every 4 iterations. {1,3,9,7}{1,3,9,7}...

We can therefore deduce that if:

($n$ mod 4) = 0, The last digit is 1

($n$ mod 4) = 1, The last digit is 3

($n$ mod 4) = 2, The last digit is 9

($n$ mod 4) = 3, The last digit is 7

---

To work out the final answer of this, let's see what happens when n = 100

$100 $ mod $4 = 0$, **Therefore the last digit is a 1!** Problem solved!

Comment: Worth emphasis is that one needs to *prove* that it is periodic in order to be rigorous. Examining a few small cases is not a proof - but may provide intuition for such.

Comment: Good point to mention, I just knew that the period would be small, as I have done similar problems in the past. But it is definitely important to make 100% sure that you have the correct pattern, and that your period is fine. For this question, 6 tests was enough

Answer (score 5):

Hint:  $3^4 \equiv 1 \mod 10$.

Answer (score 3):

If you start exponentiating $3$, you will notice the following alternating pattern for the last digit: $$3,9,7,1,$$ according as the exponent leaves a remainder $1$, $2$, $3$, or $0$, respectively, when divided by $4$. For example,
\begin{align*}
3^1=&\,\underline 3,\\
3^2=&\,\underline 9,\\
3^3=&\,2\underline 7,\\
3^4=&\,8\underline 1,\\
3^5=&\,24\underline 3,
\end{align*}
and so forth. Since $100\equiv 0(\mod 4),$ the final answer is $1$.

---

Brute-force answer: $$3^{100}=515\mathord,377\mathord,520\mathord,732\mathord,011\mathord,331\mathord,036\mathord,461\mathord,129\mathord,765\mathord,621\mathord,272\mathord,702\mathord,107\mathord,522\mathord,001.$$

Comment: It should be $3^{100}$ in your brute force answer, however someone rejected my edit :) @triple_sec

Comment: Your edit seems to have been approved by someone else since. Thanks, @JoshuaLochner. :-)

Comment: Ok great :) Good answer by the way ;)

Comment: @JoshuaLochner Thanks, I appreciate your feedback!

Answer (score 3):

We have modulo $10$$$3^{4n+k}\equiv\begin{cases}1\text{ if } k=0\\3 \text{ if } k=1\\9 \text{ if } k=2\\7\text{ if }  k=3\end{cases}$$ Thus since $100$ is multiple of $4$ $$3^4 \equiv 1 \mod 10$$

Answer (score 3):

Easy way :

$$3^{100}=(3^4)^{25}$$

$$(3^4)^{25}=81^{25}$$

If a number has $1$ as its last digit , any power of such number will have $1$ as its last digit.

So last digit of $81$ is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Short & tricky answer,
$$10 = (3^2+1) \mid (3^4-1) \mid (3^{100}-1) $$
and since $10$ is a divisor of $3^{100}-1$, the last digit of $3^{100}$ is $\color{red}{1}$.

Comment: OP may find it instructive to work out how this is equivalent to the hint I gave on the question, by translating from modular to divisibility language. To be proficient at number theory you should learn how to quickly translate between both languages.

Answer (score 1):

prove that $$3^4\equiv 1 \mod 10$$ then we get $$3^{100}\equiv 1^{25}\equiv 1 \mod 10$$

Comment: You mean mod 10.

Comment: do you mean mod 10?

Comment: Do you mean $3^{100} \equiv 1^{25} \equiv 1 \mod 10$?

Answer (score 1):

$3^{100}=(3^4)^{25 }=81^{25}=(80 + 1)^{25}=a*80^{25}+b*80^{24}+.....+x*80^2+y*80 + 1$  where a,b,c,....,y are integer coeffients obtained by expanding $(80 +1)^{25} $.  We can calculate these coefficients if we wanted to, but it's enough to know they are integers.

Notice, every term $k*80^j $ is divisible by 10 so

$3^{100}=10M + 1$ where $M= (a*80^{25}+.....+y*80)/10$.  $M $ is a whole number, so the last digit is 1.

This is more detail than we need.

It's a basic fact that if we use the notation $a \equiv b \mod n $ to mean that for integers $a,b$ and $n $ that $a$ and $b $ will have the same remainder when divided by $n $ that if $a \equiv 1 \mod n $ then $ak \equiv k \mod n $.

(Because $a \equiv 1 \mod n$ means $a=jn +1$ so $ak =(jk)n+k $ so $ak \equiv k \mod n$.)

Therefore if $a^k \equiv 1 \mod n $ than $a^{mk}=a^k*a^k*....a^k\equiv 1*1*...*1 \mod n $.

So as $3^4=81 \equiv 1 \mod 10$, it follows that $3^{4m} \equiv 1 \mod 10$ and will have 1 as a last digit.

More interesting is what are the last 2 digits of $3^{100} $.  $3^4=81 \mod 100$ so $3^8=6400+160+1\equiv 61 \mod 100$.  $3^{12} \equiv 81*61 \equiv (6+8)*10+1\equiv 41 \mod 100$.  $3^{16}\equiv 61^2\equiv (6+6)10+1\equiv 21\mod 100$.  $3^{20}\equiv 21*81\equiv (8+2)10+1 \equiv 1701 \equiv 1\mod 100$.  So $3^{20m}\equiv 1 \mod 100$ so the last two digits of $3^{100}$ are 01.

Answer (score 1):

$$3^{100}=9^{50}=(1-10)^{50}=1-50\cdot10+{50\choose2}10^2-\cdots=1+10\cdot\text{integer}$$

so the last digit is $1$.  In fact it's easy to see from this that the last two digits are $01$, and not too hard to see that the last three digits are $001$ (because the first three terms of the expansion are $1-500+62500=62001$).

Comment: More simply $\,10\mid (-9)^n-1\,$ by  $\,a\!-\!1\mid a^n-1\,$ for $\,a=-9.\,$ Don't need the Binomial Theorem. Even more trivially $\,(-9)^n\equiv 1^n\equiv 1\pmod{10}\ $